# Android: long click on a button -> perform actions

Tags: android

I want to use the same button to perform 2 different methods.
One method when user single clicks it and a second method (different) when the user LONG clicks it.

I use this for the single short click (which works great):

```
Button downSelected = (Button) findViewById(R.id.downSelected);
        downSelected.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                method();
                }
            }

        });
```

I've tried to add a longClickListener but it didn't work.

Appreciate any ideas on how to solve this.

Thanks!

Comment: you should post your complete code, what you tried with the OnLongClickListener

Answer (score 144, accepted):

I've done it before, I just used:

```
down.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Per documentation:

> public void setOnLongClickListener
>   (View.OnLongClickListener l)
>
> Since: API Level 1 Register a callback
>   to be invoked when this view is
>   clicked and held. If this view is not
>   long clickable, it becomes long
>   clickable.

Notice that it requires to return a boolean, this should work.

Comment: Thanks! Must have implanted it wrong when I tried it. the long click works but it still performs the short click method as well, any ideas?

Comment: You mean it does both or just calls the short method? What version of android is this on?

Comment: it does both :\ on Android 2.2

Comment: oh never mind, just needed to change the return false to true :)

Comment: use return false for long click only

Answer (score 20):

To get both functions working for a clickable image that will respond to both short and long clicks, I tried the following that seems to work perfectly:

```
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewCompass);
    image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            shortclick();
        }
     });

    image.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        longclick();
        return true;
    }
});
```

//Then the functions that are called:

```
 public void shortclick()
{
 Toast.makeText(this, "Why did you do that? That hurts!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

 public void longclick()
{
 Toast.makeText(this, "Why did you do that? That REALLY hurts!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

It seems that the easy way of declaring the item in XML as clickable and then defining a function to call on the click only applies to short clicks - you must have a listener to differentiate between short and long clicks.

Answer (score 17):

Initially when i implemented a longClick and a click to perform two separate events the problem i face was that when i had a longclick , the application also performed the action to be performed for a simple click . The solution i realized was to change the return type of the longClick to true which is normally false by default . Change it and it works perfectly .

Answer (score 1):

Change `return false;` to `return true;` in longClickListener

You long click the button, if it returns true then it does the work. If it returns false then it does it's work and also calls the short click and then the onClick also works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!! In KOTLIN works like this:

```
binding.someView.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Simple click!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

binding.someView.setOnLongClickListener {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Looong click!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    true
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Try using an ontouch listener instead of a clicklistener.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html

Comment: for the long click or for both?

Comment: This answer is not descriptive enough to be useful. How would you suggest the onTouchListener to be used for detecting long click?

Comment: I agree with Simon - however; you could calculate the time between between MotionEvent.DOWN and MotionEvent.UP

Answer (score -3):

The simplest and updated method is using a long click listener like

```
someView.setOnLongClickListener {
        //do your work 
        true
    }
```