# How to make an app or specific activity launched when pressing menu button or power button etc (e.g like 3 times)?

Tags: android, android-homebutton

how to make an activity in specific app(security app) started when pressing (menu or any other of the device buttons), what i should do?, i'm already have `BroadcastReceiver` in my app(to read SMS).
I'm new to android, so from where i should start? Please help me.

**Edit:** In my phone(Samsung) if i press too long on menu button one of google apps started(launched).

Comment: I don't think that is a good idea.. The purpose of home button is to bring you home (the launcher). This would result in a activity that user wouldn't generally expect.

Comment: I second Kuba comment, please don't do that since it's not a good idea. Home button is there to bring the user home or (i.e. Samsung devices) to open the task manager after a long press. Consider also, if a manufacturer will implement a behaviour like yours, unexpected things will happen.

Comment: @KubaSpatny this app i'm developing for security purposes, so what i should do to make it started when pressing on home button(see the post) even when the app is not running in background. thanx

Comment: @fasteque i don't want to disable home button functions, in my post i said (e.g like 3 times), and also said other buttons are fine (like power button). thanx

Answer (score 0):

According to the official Android documentation (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_HOME): Key code constant: Home key. This key is handled by the framework and is never delivered to applications.

Comment: Deer fasteque, if home button isn't possible what about power button(even if back)? all i want is to have a guidence to how start an app when pressing one of the device buttons when that app is off. and see the edit in the post. thanx

Comment: I suggest you to rethink/redesign your app without listening to those keys (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353647/keycode-power-only-dispatched-on-long-press) because there are serious security and usability issues.