# Android fires both onclick and onlongclick on a short click

Tags: android, onclick, onlongclicklistener

People thank you all for your thoughts. I feel quite ashamed right now, the problem was nog with the listeners, they send a message to a handler that uses a switch. One simple break statement was missing there causing the program to behave the way it did. Thanks again for your time.

i'm making an adapter class that stores quick trips possibilities for traveling via a train. This is implemented in a list. The list contains a delete button. If that one is pressed it is removed from the list. If something else is touched it should open another window, but if long pressed it should open a dialog to edit the current settings.

The problem is that on a short click both the short and long click listeners fire. If I press long only the long click is fired.

Does anyone have any suggestions/tips/answers? the code is:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
QuickTrips entry = quickTripList.get(position);

if(convertView == null) {
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.quick_trip_list, null);
}

convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    if(handler != null) {
      QuickTrips entry = (QuickTrips) v.getTag();
      Message msg = Message.obtain();
      msg.what = LAUNCH_QUICK_TRIP;
      msg.obj = entry;
      handler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
  }
});

convertView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    QuickTrips entry = (QuickTrips) v.getTag();
    Message msg = Message.obtain();
    msg.what = EDIT_QUICK_TRIP;
    msg.obj = entry;
    handler.sendMessage(msg);
    return true;
  }
});

convertView.setTag(entry);

TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText(entry.getFromTo());

Button remove = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.remove);
remove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    QuickTrips entry = (QuickTrips) v.getTag();
    quickTripList.remove(entry);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
});
remove.setTag(entry);

return convertView;
```

}

Well i tried removing the View.on... by importing it but without succes. Now i tried the onTouchListener... the problem is it only gets called on an event. To start using timers is more work then it should be, shouldn't it? I just don't understand why long click is fired on a short click

the code from the ontouchevent:

```
    convertView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    long downTime = event.getDownTime();
    long pressedTime = event.getEventTime();
    if(DEBUG) Log.i("qt", downTime + " en " + pressedTime);

    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
      if(DEBUG) Log.i("qt", "key down");
    }
    else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
      if(DEBUG) Log.i("qt", "key up");
      return true;
    } 
    else {
      if(DEBUG) Log.i("qt", "else"); //never called
    }

    return true; //if false then action up isn't called
  }
});
```

Comment: How do you know both are getting fired?

Comment: Can you post the code for your handler? Perhaps you are missing a break; when calling switch(msg.what){ case LAUNCH_QUICK_TRIP: } ?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
convertView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }
    });
```

extracted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402740/android-long-click-on-a-button-perform-actions/4402854#4402854)

Comment: How is this different than what he has in his question?

Comment: you use View.OnLongClickListener() , maybe magically things happen :D

Comment: View.OnLongClickListener() is the same as OnLongClickListener(). What you posted is the same as his code and wouldn't solve anything.

Comment: Tried it just to be sure but it didn't solve it (using it without view.on.....) now trying it with ontouch listener...