# Long Press Button Event Handler

Tags: android

I have seen several articles such as this  [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402740/android-long-click-on-a-button-perform-actions) describing how to handle a long press event with a button. I can follow these directions but I am wondering if it is possible to do it the same way I handled a click. The way I handled a click was to define the handler in XML as such:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_NextLift"
    ...
    android:onClick="btn_NextLiftClick" />
```

then in code as such:

```
public void btn_NextLiftClick(View vw_Current) 
    {...}
```

I do see the boolean property longClickable in the xml but I don't see where to define an event handler so...???

TIA
JB

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't do this via XML. Instead, use:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_NextLift);

button.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Make sure this code comes after `setContentView()` has been called.

Also, make sure that the `longClickable` property is set to true.

Comment: This is frustrating. I definitely set the code after setContentView but my button still comes up null so I get NullRef exception.

Comment: If I add the LongClick handler to the XML defined click handler then it works. It is as if my button is hiding and can't be found till it raises an event???

Comment: I was pulled off to another project and now I remember. The buttons are on a relative layout and that is the layout used by the list view for each item.

Comment: I started a new question here:           http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385435/lstview-findviewbyid-returning-null