# LstView findViewByID returning null

Tags: android, android-layout

I have several objects defined in XML that are returning null when I try to get a handle on them. I saw several post saying to clean the project but that did not help. When I explore the ListView object all the children are null?? So I am at a bit of a loss as to what I am doing wrong. Here is the code that I think is relevant but if you need to see something else let me know and I'll post it.

TIA
JB

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_NextLift"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:text="@string/str_BtnNxtTxt"
    android:onClick="btn_NextLiftClick"
    android:longClickable="true" />
```

In the activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.liftinterface);
        ...//More code....
        ...//Still in the OnCreate....
        lstvw_LiftData = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstvw_LiftData);
        ...//Image below of this object.....
        //Get a handle on our button
        Button btn_Nxt = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btn_NextLift);
        btn_Nxt.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener()
        {
         public boolean onLongClick(View v)
         {
        SaveAdvance();

        return true;
          }
        });
```

[image]

Here is my logcat errors only:

```
11-13 22:04:57.798: E/AndroidRuntime(787): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-13 22:04:57.798: E/AndroidRuntime(787): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.gpgvm.ironmike/org.gpgvm.ironmike.IcyArmActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-13 22:04:57.798: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
11-13 22:04:57.798: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
11-13 22:04:57.798: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-13 22:04:57.798: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
11-13 22:04:57.798: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-13 22:04:57.798: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-13 22:04:57.798: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-13 22:04:57.798: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 22:04:57.798: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-13 22:04:57.798: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-13 22:04:57.798: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-13 22:04:57.798: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-13 22:04:57.798: E/AndroidRuntime(787): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-13 22:04:57.798: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at org.gpgvm.ironmike.IcyArmActivity.onCreate(IcyArmActivity.java:83)
11-13 22:04:57.798: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-13 22:04:57.798: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
11-13 22:04:57.798: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Post your LogCat, so we can see what's happening.

Comment: Errors only please. But where is the Button, in `liftinterface.xml` or in the ListView?

Comment: Correct it is NOT in the liftinterface. It is in the ListView layout. I tried drilling down by getting a handle to the ListView then findById but same null result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I explore the ListView object all the children are null??

Views are not draw until *after* `onResume()` has completed. So the ListView will not have any children in `onCreate()`.

Where is this Button? If it is in the ListView, you need to write a custom adapter to override it's listeners.

---

**Addition**

> It is in the ListView layout.

You need to extend you current adapter and override `getView()` to give each row unique listeners like this. Please watch Android's Romain Guy discussion this [exact topic](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html) in fabulous detail at multiple Google Talk events.

Comment: I don't know how to give you any more points...but I would if I could. Watching that video I saw that others on this forum had guided me away from all the bad things but I learned alot of even better things and I understand even better some of the good things I was doing as well as how the even better makes it better. THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: [There](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions.html) [are](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions.html) [more](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions.html) ...

Comment: HierarchyViewer!!! That has to be by far my favorite take away from that video. Very similiar to snoop in the .NET world which I am coming from. Thanks for the directory. I'll be watching one of these a day.