# Detect button long press and press android button

Tags: android, button, ontouchlistener

I have a button, and i am trying to fire two actions in one button.
to call the method `takeVideo` on button long press. and on button press i want to call the method `imageCapture`.

the below code is working for long press. but i am not able to detect the button press to call only the `imageCapture` method.

```
takePhotoBtn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            long down;
            int action = motionEvent.getAction();
            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_BUTTON_PRESS) {
           imageCapture();
                return true;
            }
            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                    takeVideo();
                    timer.start();
                    return true;

            } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                takeVideo();
                timer.cancel();
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }


    });
```

**EDIT**

i am not using `OnLongClickListener` and `OnClickListener`.

i want to perform other actions on `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` so i am trying to solve my problem using  `setOnTouchListener` in this case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: long click on a button -> perform actions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402740/android-long-click-on-a-button-perform-actions)

Comment: Thank you but i want to solve my problem with `setOnTouchListener `

Answer (score 2):

You can get the duration of the Long Press over [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/ViewConfiguration.html#getLongPressTimeout%28%29) (`getLongPressTimeOut`) It use to be 1000ms and now 500ms... it could change. That's why you need to get the timeout.

Then, over **ACTION_DOWN** you can count the ms... if `ms >= 500` (if currently is 500ms) then is a LongPress. But, like Marios says, use the **OnLongClickListener** and **OnClickListener** for that.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use

onLongClickListener (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html)

and

OnClickListener (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html)

Comment: i want to use `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` to perform other actions, that is why i dont use onLongClickListener

Answer (score 1):

`setOnLongClickListener` can be used for this.

```
takePhotoBtn.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { 
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: i want to use `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` to perform other actions, that is why i dont use onLongClickListener