# Boolean to check if a view is being clicked

Tags: android, view, click

I have a question concerning the views in android studio:

Is there a method which returns a Boolean to indicate if a "view is on a longclick"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: long click on a button -> perform actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402740/android-long-click-on-a-button-perform-actions)

Answer (score 0):

By setting an onClickListener on it, then taking action when the listener's onClick() method is called, e.g.:

```
View btnView = view.findViewById(R.id.btnView);
btnView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't formulate my question well: I wanted to ask if
there is a method which returns a Boolean to indicate if a "view is on a longclick"

Comment: Do you mean if the user is currently clicking on the view?  If so, have a look at things like View.isInTouchMode(), isActivated(), isFocused(), isPressed() and isSelected().  I can't say which is the right one in your situation though.