# Android Click and hold to delete an item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, ontouchlistener

I'm trying to add new function, that if you click **and hold** an item from a list a window will pop up asking if you are sure you want to delete this **specific** item. Meaning if I click and hold on the first item on the list, a dialog will pop us asking if I want to delete it. And clicking yes will result in doing so.

What is the best way to achieve that?

To display files I'm currently using an **RecyclerView** and **CardView**.

**Code and picture below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:transitionName="open_mediaplayer"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardElevation="3dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
                    
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:id="@+id/file_name_text"
                        android:text="Audio File_2244322"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                        android:id="@+id/file_length_text"
                        android:text="00:44"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/file_time_added"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:text="30-12-2019"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            
        </LinearLayout>
        
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is how it looks like

[image: This is how it looks like]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: long click on a button -> perform actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402740/android-long-click-on-a-button-perform-actions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `View.OnLongClickListener` on your item in RecyclerView. When the listener is triggered, display an alert asking if the user really wants to delete the item. If yes, delete the item wherever it's necessary (at least in the dataset) and update the RecyclerView using `adapter.notifyItemRemoved(indexOfDeletedElement)`