# How to show information about a view(such as a button) on long press?

Tags: android, android-studio

I wanted to show information about a button on long pressing that button, like in the image shown below. I am new to android and any help would be highly appreciated  .[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPyxe.png)

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: If you are coding in Kotlin, use this,: button.setOnLongClickListener{//write here what you want to do}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `tooltipText` , just add this like below:

```
<Button
    ...
    android:tooltipText="{Hint String}" />
```

Comment: Thanks a million ❤️

Answer (score 0):

If it's a button (or infact any `View`), use the `setOnLongClickListener` method.

```
button.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Refer: [Android: long click on a button -> perform actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402740/android-long-click-on-a-button-perform-actions)